# SSL Error with EAP-TLS FreeRadius

Tags: ssl, freeradius, eap

My RADIUS Server is configured for EAP-TLS. I have a valid Server Certificate, Private Key and Fullchain file. When testing the authentication with a Client Certificate using `eapol_test` i get the error message:

```
(10) eap_tls:   ERROR: SSL says error 20 : unable to get local issuer certificate
(10) eap_tls: >>> send TLS 1.2  [length 0002] 
(10) eap_tls: ERROR: TLS Alert write:fatal:unknown CA
tls: TLS_accept: Error in error
(10) eap_tls: ERROR: Failed in __FUNCTION__ (SSL_read): error:1417C086:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
(10) eap_tls: ERROR: System call (I/O) error (-1)
(10) eap_tls: ERROR: TLS receive handshake failed during operation
(10) eap_tls: ERROR: [eaptls process] = fail
(10) eap: ERROR: Failed continuing EAP TLS (13) session.  EAP sub-module failed
(10) eap: Sending EAP Failure (code 4) ID 228 length 4
(10) eap: Failed in EAP select
(10)     [eap] = invalid
(10)   } # authenticate = invalid
(10) Failed to authenticate the user
```

Does this mean, that the RADIUS Server cant find the Fullchain File? Or is this a Client Issue?